# Python Image.load() returning pixels greater than 250

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel, image-load

I am loading my Image file using Image.open("image.tif"). Then i am using Image.load() to generate a pixelMap of the image. Then i am storing each pixel into an array. The following code describes this process. Then I want to create the ascii value of each pixel and store it in a string. So I going through each pixel in my pixel array and then change the pixel value to ascii value. However I am having an error because I am getting some pixel values greater than 250. How is this possible. Also, it is b/w image. What am I doing wrong?

```
self.filename = filename
self.im = Image.open(filename)
self.pixelmap = self.im.load() #Loads the image as a map of pixels
self.arr = []
for i in range(self.im.size[0]):
    for j in range(self.im.size[1]):
    mypixel = self.pixelmap[i, j]
    self.arr.append(mypixel)


for i in msgFile.arr:
    self.message += str(unichr(int(i)))
```

Comment: What is *'I'm having an error'*? What exact error message do you get?

Comment: Also, the pixel value type returned by ``load`` is image type dependent. For example GIF returns a pallet index value, where as JPEG returns an R,G,B tuple.

Comment: i am getting the error that the unichr value is exceeding 128. I changed the code to self.mesasge += str(chr(int(i)))

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = np.asarray(Image.open('image.jpg'))
_y, _x, _z = image.shape
str_array = [str(image[y][x]) for y in range(_y) for x in range(_x)]
```